# Get the funding type from stripe element

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to fetch if the card `funding` type `credit, debit, prepaid, etc`, I'm using front-end Stripe.js so I figured it would be great if I can use the card object from the stripe API.

However I'm trying to do so without having to use an API call as to not expose the secret key. While I can generate token with the publishable key, I cannot use it to fetch card details.

Is there a way to fetch this specific detail from the card without the need to use secret key/ or to fetch it the same way Stripe.js fetches the card `brand` such as visa, mastercard, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Stripe.js to [create a PaymentMethod](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method) with a publishable key. That method returns a [PaymentMethod object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-funding) which will have the card's funding type included.